# Different scale on the axes in different parts of the graph

Tags: pgfplots

How to make different scaling of axes on different parts of the graph, as, for example, shown in this figure. I have a similar graph, but I don't like that the points at the beginning are too close to the Y axis due to the fact that the X coordinates are small, how can I fix it? [image]

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   scale only axis, % The height and width argument only apply to the actual axis
    height=8cm,
    width=15cm,
    enlargelimits=true,
    axis lines = middle, % привычные оси со стрелочками с пересечением в нуле
    % возможные значения: box, left, middle, center, right, none
    xlabel = {$f$, кГц}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$K(f)$}, % подпись оси y 
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    grid=major, % м.б. еще both - и там и там
    grid style={dotted, cyan},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(0.02,0.8)
(0.1,0.8)
(0.2,0.75)
(0.5,0.7)
(1,0.6)
(2,0.4)
(5,0.25)
(10,0.15)
(15,0.1)
(20,0.07)
(50,0.034)
(100,0.016)
(200,0.008)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 }
\caption{График }
  \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could log-scale the *x* axis using `semilogxaxis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You may want to try `semilogxaxis` instead of `axis` which will log-scale the *x* axis:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    scale only axis, % The height and width argument only apply to the actual axis
    height=8cm,
    width=15cm,
    axis lines=left, % привычные оси со стрелочками с пересечением в нуле
    % возможные значения: box, left, middle, center, right, none
    axis line shift=10pt,
    xlabel={$f$, кГц}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel={$K(f)$}, % подпись оси y 
    grid=major, % м.б. еще both - и там и там
    grid style={dotted, cyan},
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xtick={0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200},
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (0.02,0.8)
    (0.1,0.8)
    (0.2,0.75)
    (0.5,0.7)
    (1,0.6)
    (2,0.4)
    (5,0.25)
    (10,0.15)
    (15,0.1)
    (20,0.07)
    (50,0.034)
    (100,0.016)
    (200,0.008)
};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]